# Libgdx screen render function being called but not drawing

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been having a problem with the rendering in my screens.

Basically I have an overall class that extends Game and I have created a few other classes for the various pages for my game such as the Main Menu, the actual game etc.  When I call setScreen(screen) on one of these classes the rendering loop of that screen is called, but I cant seem to draw anything.

What I have done is that I created the orthographic camera and spritebatch in the overall game class and passed it to the screens through their constructor method.  However, I don't seem to be able to draw anything.  The screen still clears the background.

Sorry I don't have my source code at the moment but here is roughly what it looks like:

This is my overall game class:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

public OrthographicCamera camera;
public SpriteBatch batch;
public ResourceManager Rm;

public StartScreen MainMenu;
public GameScreen CellTD;
public InstructionsScreen Instructions;
public PauseScreen Pause;

@Override
public void create() {      
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    Rm = new ResourceManager();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1.0f, h/w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Rm.LoadTexture("Cell.png");

    MainMenu = new StartScreen(camera, batch, Rm, this);
    CellTD = new GameScreen(camera, batch, Rm, this);
    Instructions = new InstructionsScreen(camera, batch, Rm, this);
    Pause = new PauseScreen(camera, batch, Rm, this);

    setScreen(MainMenu);

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

}
```

This is one of my screen classes:

```
public class StartScreen implements Screen{

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private ResourceManager Rm;
private int SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H;
public MyGdxGame Parent;
private Label Title;
private Sprite s;

StartScreen(OrthographicCamera c, SpriteBatch b, ResourceManager r, MyGdxGame g)
{
    camera = c;
    batch = b;
    Rm = r;
    SCREEN_W = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    SCREEN_H = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    Parent = g;

    camera.setToOrtho(false,1.0f,SCREEN_H/SCREEN_W);
    camera.update();

    Title = new Label("Cell TD",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/CellTDFont.fnt"),false) ,new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)));
    Title.setText("Cell TD");
    Title.setSize(1.0f, SCREEN_H/SCREEN_W);
    Title.setOrigin(Title.getWidth()/2, Title.getHeight()/2);
    Title.setPosition(0, 0);

    s = new Sprite(Rm.GetTexture("Cell.png"));
    s.setSize(1.0f, SCREEN_H/SCREEN_W);
    s.setOrigin(s.getWidth()/2, s.getHeight()/2);
    s.setPosition(-0.5f, -SCREEN_H/SCREEN_W/2);
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0.9f, 0.9f, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    //Title.draw(batch,1);
    s.draw(batch);

    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Put the code as it really is. Its very hard to know what problem do you have like this.

Answer (score 0):

Its an easy bug.
Your camera is not correct i guess.

```
c = new OrthographicCamera(1.0f,h/w);
```

this means that the camera is 1px width and h/w height... and your sprite is like 100x200 for example. So the only thing you will see is around 1px of the sprite.

Do change the constructor of it to something liket this:

```
float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); //the width of the window
float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();//the height of the window

camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
```

Dont forget to resize the camera inside of the resize.

maybe take a look at the new libgdx wiki here:

1. [Orthographic camera](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera)
2. [Spritebatch, textureregions, and sprite](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-textureregions,-and-sprite)

Comment: But i resized my sprite to be smaller.  It works when I put my render code in the parent game class rather than in the screens

Comment: You can't show a sprite at 1px. Your parents class might note have the same viewport of the camera. It has nothing todo with the render, it's just the camera that does not have the right size. As mentioned you have like 1px that you show at the screen so you see only 1px of the sprite.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now.